# Where are published messages kept while RabbitMQ brokers are in a blocked state?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I noticed that when brokers are in a blocked state due to high watermark messages will not be accepted. However when they get unblocked the messages that are sent when the brokers were in a blocked state are accepted again (while the publisher is down, so they are not being republished).

Where are the messages kept? Is there a maximum amount of messages that can be kept like this, and how do I see how many? Is this behavior configurable?

I'm using a CachingConnectionFactory with a publisherConfirm in order to confirm messages are ack'd, but in this case it results in false information. The publisher confirm times out, but the broker eventually processes the message anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel` has a logic like this:

```
public void quiescingTransmit(AMQCommand c) throws IOException {
    synchronized (_channelMutex) {
        if (c.getMethod().hasContent()) {
            while (_blockContent) {
                try {
                    _channelMutex.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                // This is to catch a situation when the thread wakes up during
                // shutdown. Currently, no command that has content is allowed
                // to send anything in a closing state.
                ensureIsOpen();
            }
        }
        this._trafficListener.write(c);
        c.transmit(this);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that  `while (_blockContent) {`, so technically a publishing thread is blocked over here and there is no any internal queues to buffer messages until it is unblocked. We just don't go anywhere else.

See more info in official RabbitMQ docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html

And also see Spring AMQP docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#blocked-connections-and-resource-constraints